# Navigation Bar and AJAX loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following setup:

A **main-page.php** that is consisted of:

1) A header

2) A nav bar

3) Content (is loaded inside a `<div id="dynamic-content"></div>`)

4) Footer

Inside the nav bar you find several options (ex. About Us, Contact Us, etc..).

Lets say that the script responsible for "**About Us**" is called **about-us.php**.

What i want to achieve is to load the output of **about-us.php** page inside the content area (aka the dynamic-content div), as soon as i press the "About Us" button (#about-us div).

In order to achieve this i use the following AJAX call:

**AJAX Call**

```
$("#about-us").on('click', function(){

   $.ajax({
              url: "about-us.php",
              success: function(output){

                   $("#dynamic-content").html(output);

              }
         });

});
```

Both **main-page.php** and **about-us.php** include their own CSS and JavaScript files:

**main-page.js** and **main-page.css** included in main-page.php

**about-us.js** and **about-us.css** included in about-us.php

**THE QUESTION:**

What is the correct way to use CSS and Javascript files of **about-us.php**?
Should i include them inside the **about-us.php** script or include them inside the **main-page.php**?

When i include them inside about-us.php i get an alert from console saying "*Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience*".

At this point i have to mention that the about-us.js has more AJAX requests..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to include your JS and css in the main-page.php. As you mentioned that the About Us navigation would just change the dynamic content, then it should only change the data. All the scripts and style sheets should be loaded before that.

Comment: Lets say that the JS file of About Us is included in the main-page.php. Loading main-page.php it loads the about-us.js script as well. What if that script is targeting an element that is not yet present in main-page.php DOM?

Comment: Even if the script targets an element that is not present, a check should also be present to ensure the presence of such an element. So before you use that element, make sure it exists.

Comment: How can i invoke a JS file included in main-page.php, as soon as the external content is loaded inside main-page.php? For example include the about-us.js inside main-page.php and invoke it as soon as the about-us.php content is loaded?

Comment: Once your JS file is loaded in the browser, you can use the contents of it (functions, variables, etc.) until you load a totally different html page. That means, there is no explicit "invoking" of javascript file, as it is already present. You can invoke/call a function inside the JS file, on a user action.For example , you invoke a function in about-us.js when user clicks on some link on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both.
But if you add js. and css of about-us.php in about-us.php file then it will be better.
That means those js and css will be loaded only when user clicks button which is better.

Although you have to ensure that the "class" "id" used in both css files(about-us.css and mainpage.css) must be different otherwise ids and classes of mainpage.css will be overridden by aboutus.css ids or classes.